# Android like Text Auto Link property in BlackBerry

Tags: android, blackberry, textfield

Is there any Text Auto Link property in BlackBerry similar to Android.

Means in Android if a text has a URL with in the text and Texts Auto Link property is set then it automatically detects the URL and convert it to a hyperlink.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a Class called as `ActiveRichTextField` in the Blackberry SDK which accepts STrings and creates links in it automatically if they are `phone numbers` `emails adrs` `URLS`

Try using that.